# scatter plot from different data via matplotlib

Tags: matplotlib

My question is simple.Hot to make the two scatter plot in  one figure?
There is error if I just write the two  `pl.scatter` one by one.

```
a,b,c=np.loadtxt('mydata',usecols=(0,1,2),delimiter=",",unpack=True)
pl.scatter(a,b,color='g',s=0.5,'b')
pl.scatter(b,c,'r')
```

The other question is how to use the left y and right y axis together,say,the first scatter plot use the left y axis and,the second scatter plot use the right y axis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `ax.twinx()` to create a second y-axis that shares the same x-axis

```
ax1 = pl.axes()
ax2 = ax1.twinx()
ax1.scatter(a,b,color='g',s=0.5)
ax2.scatter(b,c,color='r')
```

The error you were seeing is probably because you have a non-keyword argument (`'b'`) after a keyword argument (`color='r'`).